# How does React render DOM without refreshing page?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

Before I met React, When I made changes on the browser using Javascript I had to refresh page manuelly(or with live server) to see changes. But react does that without refreshing page.

I'm trying to learn hooks in React. According to tutors When I change any state by using `useState` in React, React automatically renders whole component which has that state. But while doing that React doesn't refresh page. How does it possible ? Even if  React  only changed a small part of DOM, wouldn't it be necessary to refresh the page to see the change?
Because at the end of the day React is just javascript and eventually renders DOM

Comment: _"When I made changes on the browser using Javascript I had to refresh page manuelly"_ In that case you did something wrong. How did you modify the DOM? Changing the DOM is immediately visible in the browser without reload. You can start with https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document_Object_Model/Introduction

Comment: How so ? For example I created h1 tag in html. When I try to change it's innerHTML by using Javasciprt I have to refresh page to see changes

Comment: No, you don't. Can you provide a [mcve]? Modifications with `innerHTML` are immediately visible in the browser. Here is an example: https://jsfiddle.net/q6n0aLfb/

Comment: Yes, in the link you sent, it automatically making changes but I think under the hood browser refreshing itself in that link. When I create an html page in my local computer and open it via any browser(chrome, mozilla etc) I can't see changes If ı don't refresh page

Comment: Do you see error messages in the dev tools? Do you have extensions to disable JavaScript in your browser? Your question and your comments don't make much sense. A reload resets the state of the website. You shouldn't see any changes after the reload.

Comment: There is no error in devtools and I never have

Comment: I think you are making confusion between page refresh in order to see new code execution during development, and actual JS code execution. If you are using CRA, CRA uses webpack HotReload module during development to auto refresh  the browser page with new code each time you change your code. It's not something related to React, you can use an Hot Reload module even with vanilla jS you just have to set up webpack properly.

Comment: I added an input field to the website. You can write anything into the input field while JavaScript modifies the website. That proofs that the page isn't reloaded. https://jsfiddle.net/r2wzo1Ln/

Comment: So, How come I can't see changes if I don't refresh the page ?

Comment: Maybe your browser or computer is broken or you're using something like No Script to disable JavaScript. The rest of the world sees the changes. That's how modern websites work. But since you can see the live changes in jsfiddle, it seems like your dev environment is broken or misconfigured. Do you use a dev server? Are you blocking JavaScript in local files?

Comment: Now ı tried two different computer. Maybe I couldn't explain the problem I have or there is misunderstanding.

Comment: Yes, there is a misunderstanding. The misunderstanding is that DOM manipulations require a refresh. This is wrong, and I'm not sure how to explain it further than that. A page refresh means fetching new HTML/JS from the server (or cache). That means any JS needs to **re-run** completely from the start. DOM manipulations from a previous page load would actually be **lost**, not take affect.

Comment: Do you see an input field and a counter counting up every second: https://jsfiddle.net/r2wzo1Ln/ If you can see it, it proves that you can immediately see DOM manipulations without page reload. If you can't see it, something is broken or misconfigured on your side.

Comment: *Yes, in the link you sent, it automatically making changes but I think under the hood browser refreshing itself in that link* - nope, no refresh happening.

Comment: @CesarePolonara thanks a lot. That's what I need. I really understood difference between them. Thanks a lot

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I think you are making confusion between page refresh in order to see new code execution during development, and actual JS code execution. If you are using CRA, CRA uses webpack Hot Module Replacement during development to auto refresh the browser page with new code each time you change your JS/CSS code. It's not something related to React, you can use HMR feature even with vanilla JS you just have to set up webpack properly.

More info here: https://webpack.js.org/concepts/hot-module-replacement/

Comment: This answer doesn't answer the question _"How does React render DOM without refreshing page?"_ in no way and is useless for future user searching for similar topics.

Comment: That question title itself did not make sense,, probably due to op confusion about the topic, but I was able to understand what he meant and what was confusing him... I think it would be more useful to edit the title ... It was clear to me he was confused by the fact he had hot reload on dev web server while developing with create-react-app and he had never seen such a feature while probably developing with static html, css and js files and no bundlers...

Comment: Stack Overflow is a question and answer platform to help future users to find solutions for similar problems. It's not a forum to help one user with a problem. This answer isn't helpful because it doesn't answer the actual question. It answers something, the OP meant but didn't ask. The question asks about DOM manipulation in vanilla JS and React, but your answer doesn't explain anything of it.

Comment: I think it would be more constructive to edit the title of the question so it respects both the op's original intention and future visitors... Since the body of the question looks pretty clear to me, it's the title to be deceptive... It's also evident that english language is not op's main language, so I would try to be more comprehensive...

Comment: The body of the question is about hooks and states in React. Where does your answer mention them? The first sentence of the question _"When I made changes on the browser using Javascript I had to refresh page manuelly"_. The whole question has nothing to do with your answer. And your answer doesn't explain why you have to reload the page with vanilla JS, but not with React.